# Database design and normalization in django

Tags: python, django, database

I have a web form where a student can enter their info and grades e.g.

- Name
- Age
- Math Grade
- Spanish Grade
- Chemistry Grade

This would transform to a POST request like below:

```
POST /grades
{
 "name": "Bob",
 "age": 17,
 "math_grade": "A",
 "spanish_grade": "B",
 "chemistry_grade": "C",
}
```

Finally, this would be stored in a SQL table `grades` like below by django ORM:

| Name | Age | Subject | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 17 | Math | A |
| Bob | 17 | Spanish | B |
| Bob | 17 | Chemistry | C |

All good till here.

---

As I read about the different normal forms (1NF, 2NF, 3NF), it seems like the above table should really be two tables (`student` and `grades`) or maybe even three (`student`, `subject` DIMENSION table, `grades` FACT table).

Q1. If the `grades` table should really be split, should I do it at the application level where django ORM executes SQL query against multiple tables at once or am I pre-optimizing here? Should I do the normalization as part of my data warehousing strategy and leave the application table as-is?

Q2. If I want to return the grades for Bob in a nested format like below, how would I do that in django.

```
GET /grades/Bob
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 17,
  "grades": {
     "math": "A",
     "spanish": "B",
     "chemistry": "C",
   }
}
```

These look like seemingly obvious questions, not sure if/what am I missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions and facts are types of table used in analytical (OLAP) systems are rarely in normalised forms.

If you are looking at creating a transactional (OLTP) system then it would usually be in a 3NF format. If the data you are showing is really all the information you have then 2 tables would be the best design: student and subject/grade.

In the real world you are likely to have much more information about a subject (level, duration, etc) so you would have a student table, a subject table and an intersection table holding the grade, date awarded, etc.